# Let for loop wait until code finish execution javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

I have a bubble sort function that when the a swap occurs it should show it visibly. But after lots of approaches it continues executing the loops without waiting for the animation to stop. (we are only allowed to use JavaScript). Is there a way to tell the website to wait for the animation to complete. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) 
{

    for (var j = 0, swapping, endIndex = len - i; j < endIndex; j++) 
    {
        if (marksArr[j] > marksArr[j + 1]) 
        {
            //swap objects




            /*(function() {
                var k = 0,
                    action = function() {
                        document.getElementById(coursesKey[j]).style.top = (parseInt(document.getElementById(coursesKey[j]).style.top) + 1) + 'px';
                        document.getElementById(coursesKey[j + 1]).style.top = (parseInt(document.getElementById(coursesKey[j+1]).style.top) - 1) + 'px'; 

                        k++;
                        if (k < difMoves) {
                            setTimeout(action, 200);
                        }
                    };

                setTimeout(action, 200);
            })();*/



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't have the loop wait *and* have the browser redraw. As long as there's some blocking code, you won't be able to update the UI, and if you don't block the loop will continue. One simple possibility would be to push all the visual updates to an Array, then after the loop is done, print the content of the Array to the browser using `setInterval()` or a series of `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Can't you some how say go to this function and if the function is completed continue with the for loop?

Comment: Not when you use `setTimeout`. What you're describing is blocking the loop. You can do that by calling the function without `setTimeout`, but then the UI won't be updated until the loop is done. What you seem to want is to hold the loop in place, and also have the UI reflect the update you made. This is impossible in JavaScript.

Comment: What alternative can I use for the for loops?

Comment: Are you cheating your computer science homework on Stackoverflow? ;)

Comment: @user2342875: the problem has nothing to do with the `for` loop per se. The issue is your desire to update the UI while synchronous code is running. I offered a simple solution above. It's much easier to handle the asynchronous breaks needed to update the UI if you do it using a simple Array that you've already built.

Comment: Ill try it and no I am not cheating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @cookie monster already explained, you can't block loops in JavaScript and update the UI using `setTimeout()` at the same time (this is because JavaScript is essentially single-threaded).

The most elegant solution would be "recording" each animation step while the `for` loops process the array, and then run the animation afterwards, e.g. using `setTimeout()`. Some time ago, [I've implemented this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14803334/1350193) for a similar question on StackOverflow; here's a demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aletheios/VZ92p/)

The code can also be simplified:

```
function swap(list, i1, i2) {
    var tmp = list[i1];
    list[i1] = list[i2];
    list[i2] = tmp;
}

function animateBubblesort(list) {
    var animationSteps = [];

    // Sort array
    for (var n = list.length; n > 1; --n) {
        for (var i = 0; i < n-1; ++i) {
            if (list[i] > list[i+1]) {
                swap(list, i, i+1);
                // Add new step (clone of current array) to "animation queue"
                animationSteps.push(list.slice(0));
            }
        }
    }

    // Print animated steps (using setInterval() for simplicity)
    var count = 0, 
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            console.log(animationSteps[count]);
            if (++count >= animationSteps.length) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 250);
}

animateBubblesort([5,8,2,4,1,9,7,3,0,6]);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r6pW3/)

Another (less intuitive) possibility would be to implement the algorithm without loops in order to get control over when the next step of the algorithm is executed (so you have time for your animation). Here's an example: [DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/kQ62d/)